# php: get content of a protected page?

Tags: php, curl, get

I am trying to get the html code of a protected page. I am aiming to restyle this page with css, so I need tho get the html code first !!!

I have a valid username and password.

I have tried to use cURL, but I always end up with this message: "the stub received bad data"

the url of the page is: http://student.guc.edu.eg

Comment: Have you tried "view source"?

Comment: Try googling for `php curl http authentication`. See this in the manual for an example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98164

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have any code already? You need to use code such as this, utilising `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` and `CURLOPT_USERPWD` specifically.

```
$username = 'studentid';
$password = 'studentpassword';

$ch = curl_init("http://student.guc.edu.eg/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

`CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`

The HTTP authentication method(s) to use. The options are: CURLAUTH_BASIC, CURLAUTH_DIGEST, CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE, CURLAUTH_NTLM, CURLAUTH_ANY, and CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE.

The bitwise | (or) operator can be used to combine more than one method. If this is done, cURL will poll the server to see what methods it supports and pick the best one.

CURLAUTH_ANY is an alias for CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_DIGEST | CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.

CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE is an alias for CURLAUTH_DIGEST | CURLAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE | CURLAUTH_NTLM.

`CURLOPT_USERPWD`

A username and password formatted as "[username]:[password]" to use for the connection.

---

Looking at the headers returned from the site http://student.guc.edu.eg/, it's as follows:

```
> curl -I http://student.guc.edu.eg/
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.0
Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2011 08:18:34 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="student.guc.edu.eg"
Connection: close
Content-Length: 4431
Content-Type: text/html
```

This means that rather than using `CURLAUTH_BASIC`, you should try `CURLAUTH_NTLM`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @ahmed The web server that you are using. The only place I've ever seen "The stub received bad data" is on Windows.

Comment: @ahmed, okay, so using my code above, what happens? Is it simply the `$html` variable that contains 'The stub received bad data'?

Comment: update, when I cahnged (CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH) to (CURLAUTH_ANY), I got the (You are not authorized to view this page) page !!!

Comment: @ahmed Well this is obviously being returned by the server, are your username and password correct? I don't think this is *your* problem..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they are correct :/
my password contains the dash symbol ( - ) if it makes a different ?!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cURL, use a class someone else has written which takes away all the hassle of remembering to send the correct headers, producing useful error messages etc.., such as Zend_Http_Client:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html